# PHP giving strange diff. in time

Tags: php

Hi i have a script its returning time diff. on diff. computer when all on same network it return time same on Site but when 1 comp. is on diff. network it return diff. time

i am struggling with this i know php is server side language i have checked there is not any JavaScript code for this so its not taking Client time

its using

```
 <?php
 echo time();
 ?>
```

i can't able to post Full code but its using time() and then subtracting from saved mysql time

Comment: Can you put a bit more details in here? Like do the different computers use different timezones.

The mysql-time you mentioned where is it calculated.....on the same server that calculates the php time, or another one? (If different servers do they have the same time/do they use the same time server, ...)

These infos would help a lot to see where your problem comes from.

Comment: no diff. computer has same timezon +5:30

the mysql time is entered by us in Timestamp format its on same server

Comment: is there a difference of a few seconds or a whole minute/hour ?

Comment: few seconds some time 1 min. but not more then it

Comment: Try to enter the time in this format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MN in the database. Try out this code `date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date("Y-m-d G:i",time());`

Answer (score 5):

I thought you might want to set the time zone

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: Include the line: date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); at the very top of the php files (after any session_start()) as Xingjia Luo suggested. This way they should both have the same time, or you could put it in an include file if you have a common session handler include. It may pay to try having a fresh file on both servers with only the time checks to ensure no code contamination. Also - silly idea maybe, but have you checked the timezone set on the servers actually match and are correct?

Comment: If you set the mysql time zone default-time-zone=timezone

Comment: how to set mysql time zone ?? @Chris i don't think server timezone and what we set in PHP files matter i mean they don't have to match or they ?? what you think..

Comment: The server timezones dont have to match no. But to make it easier it pays to set the timezone in the PHP file at run time. Im pretty sure there is a way of setting the connection timezone if you are using mysql to create an auto timestamp, else it wont matter